# Why to use base.LoadContent in Game Components

Tags: .net, xna

Why does the game Component have a call to `base.LoadContent()`?My Game works fine when I removed all such calls to Base?

As i think,`base.Update()` and `base.Draw()` are used to keep the Components in Sync with the Game. Is that Correct or any other reasons are there?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is lacking in detail. When you say 'the game component', are you talking about one you've written, or the base GameComponent class? If you're asking why your game components need to have a call to base.LoadContent(), this is so the base class, XNA.GameComponent can receive the call to LoadContent to do whatever XNA has designed GameComponent to do (like register for update() calls, for example).

Answer (score 2):

The only base.whatever call that you need to be careful of in the XNA base game template is the call to base.Initialize(). The rest of them call empty methods in the base game class and can be removed with no consequences/unexpected behavior.

For more details on the base game class and it's order of operations and what's going on behind the scenes, Nick Gravelyn did a great write-up a while back that walks you through it all. You can read that here -> http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2008/11/life-of-an-xna-game/

Comment: Looks like a dead link

Answer (score 0):

The base class GameComponent does a lot of not so obvious stuff behind the curtains, without you realizing it. You have to make sure you always call the base methods (unless you know very well what you are doing), so that the game components are in the state XNA expects them to be. In the specific case of LoadContent, I don't think anything would be missing, but I cannot assure it.

In the case of Initilize, for example, GameComponent.Initialize () is the method in charge of invoking this.LoadContent (), so not including a call to base.Initialize () in your derived classes would prevent your game from loading any graphics, fonts and such, unless you do it by yourself.

It is also important to note that you might later move objects down the component hierarchy, and then you'd have to add all the calls to base you failed to include originally.

Comment: but if these are some basic behind the curtain stuffs,they should be as the 1st line in the constructor perhpas?

Comment: No, because each of the operations executed has certain requirements. For example, a call to LoadContent before GameObject.Initialize is called would crash your game, because not all info has been set yet. Think of all this as a pipeline for GameObjects, with each step relying on the previous ones.